# Django Raw SQL Not Getting ID

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get information from my database table from a search. On the site I'm working on a user enters some text into a searchbox and are provided with a list of results, which they can then click to find more information. Now the thing thats stumping me is, I can get this working perfectly with the following code:

views.py

```
from models import Person
from django.template.loader import get_template 
from django.template import Context

def search(request):
   q = request.GET.get("q")
if q:
   results = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
else:
   results = Person.objects.all()  

context = dict(results=results, q=q)
return render(request, "results.html", context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class Person(models.Model):
name = models.TextField()
job = models.TextField()
website = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from search.models import Person

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Person.objects.all(),
        template_name="search.html")),

    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(
        model=Person,
        template_name="single.html")),

    url(r'^results/$', 'search.views.search'),
)
```

results snippet

```
{% for person in results %}
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="/search/{{person.id}}">{{ person.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

And it works, however I discovered that I need to change some text to wildcards so I would need to go the SQL route. Here is the different code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Person
import re
from django.template.loader import get_template 
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection

def search(request):
q = request.GET.get("q")
moddedq = re.sub(r"(\s\d\s)","%",q)

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM search_person WHERE name LIKE %s''', [moddedq])
row = cursor.fetchone()


context = dict(results=results, q=q, moddedq=moddedq, row=row)
return render(request, "results.html", context)
```

results snippet

```
{% for person in row %}
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="/search/{{person.id}}">{{ person.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

However that just creates a list with each part of the persons info, whereas the initial code just displayed the name and upon clicking the name the extra information was available. I've noticed that the ID is not being pulled from the SQL so the hyperlink I'm trying to create just brings back to the search page. My 2 main issues are:

ID Not being pulled
All user info appearing in a list

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I can't see any reason to use raw SQL here; `Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)` would work absolutely fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchone()` returns `tuple`, not model

```
{% for person in row %}
<li class="list-group-item"><a href="/search/{{ person.0 }}">{{ person.1 }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, by switching to fetchall as opposed to fetchone it works exactly as intended. I need more rep to upvote this answer but as soon as I get it I will return! Thanks again!